# Wordpress: Multiple Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

After long search with no luck, finally I have decided to ask here.

I am creating WordPress theme and need to add multiple custom post type for some additional featured which I will use rapidly or can say that will be my main use for the site.

Adding single custom post type there is not problem but I want to add more than two, three or more in future. I have tried to use same code by changing register post type name but its not working and giving some error.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me to create multiple post type with multiple taxonomy and post tag for each CPT.

I will really thankful and appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! However I don't want to use any plugin for that, its make website bit slower and even for learning purpose I want to know whats wrong I am doing!

As I said above I am just using same code for another custom post type as first just only changing name so will appreciate your guidance to solve this.

Comment: Here is the modified script http://snipt.org/kglkm1. Tested and works good. Thanks

Comment: Wow you are amazing... it works just now only few things remains yet.. how to add metabox and column to all?

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin which is very easy to use

[custom post type maker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-maker/)